# Synchronously Create Image Object from DataURI using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, uri, data-uri

does anyone know if it's possible to synchronously create an image object from a data uri using JavaScript?  It is possible to create an image object from a data URI asynchronously like this:

```
            imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.onload = function() {
                callback(imageObj);
            };
            imageObj.src = dataURI;
```

You might think that this would work:

```
            imageObj = new Image();
            imageObj.src = dataURI;
            callback(imageObj);
```

But if I remember correctly, this fails in some browsers.

Ideas?

Comment: what happens in the first example? Should work as the onload function MUST be defined before you change the source

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `complete` attribute of `Image` object.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_complete.asp

Before calling `callback` function, in a loop, you can continuously check whether `complete` is `true`. Once its true, then it is loaded.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to instantly change a data URI into an image object.  Using a polling technique to determine if the image has loaded, in my opinion, is worse than hooking into the onload event.